# Jboss EAP 7 - Try to complete last failed message even after restart

Tags: jboss-eap-7

I am using Jboss EAP 7.4 and my application is JMS based. We are facing a strange issue. When there is any exception in application, it reurns the response and then keep continue executing the request. I can see sevaral database connection and log files are grtting filled.Even, if i stop the application server and start again, it tries to execute the last message only.

Thanks,